# Passing a node as parameter to a XSL stylesheet

Tags: xslt, exist-db, exslt

I need to pass a node as a parameter to an XSL stylesheet. The issue is that the parameter gets sent as a string. I have seen the several SO questions regarding this topic, and I know that the solution (in XSLT 1.0) is to use an external `node-set()` function to transform the string to a node set.

My issue is that I am using eXist DB I cannot seem to be able to get its XSLT processor to locate any such function. I have tried the EXSLT `node-set()` from the namespace `http://exslt.org/common` as well as both the Saxon and Xalan version (I think eXist used to use Xalan but now it might be Saxon).

Are these extensions even allowed in the XSLT processor used by eXist? If not, is there something else I can do?

Comment: Well, you can first check details of your used XSLT processor with a stylesheet like http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/processorTest3.xml to output properties like `system-property('xsl:vendor')` and `system-property('xsl:product-version')`. As for your current attempts, are you using Java code to perform the XSLT transformation, or XQuery? Consider to show details of that code passing the parameter and running the transformation.

Comment: You don't want to read other similar SO questions/answers unless they relate specifically to eXist, because the way of passing parameters to an XSLT transformation depends on the details of the API offered by the particular product, and that varies from one product to another. And it is NOT the purpose of the node-set() function to parse XML supplied as a string, though some implementations do that.

Comment: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/transform&location=java:org.exist.xquery.functions.transform.TransformModule&details=true says about the parameters "Stylesheet parameters may be passed in the third argument using an XML fragment with the following structure: `<parameters><param name="param-name1" value="param-value1"/></parameters>`". That looks as if parameters, at least for the `transform` function, are simply name/value string pairs.

Comment: And https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/blob/develop/src/org/exist/xquery/functions/transform/Transform.java#L474 seems does seem to confirm that parameters are treated as java.util.Properties. But hopefully some exist user or developer can provide a more informed answer.

Comment: @Martin Honnen Yes, I am indeed using the XQuery function transform:transform() to run the transformation. And I think you're right. The <param> seems strip any XML tags that are passed to it. So I don't think the node can be recreated at all.

Comment: @Michael Kay Even though it might not be the purpose of the `node-set()` function you should be able to use it for that, at least the EXSLT version. Its documentation says: _You can also use this function to turn a string into a text node, which is helpful if you want to pass a string to a function that only accepts a node-set._
http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/

Comment: @pajevic I am afraid you are misinterpreting what the `node-set()` function does. To "*turn a string into a text node*" does NOT mean parsing escaped markup as if it were XML and turning it into a node-set. For this, you would need a function such as `parse-xml()` which is available in XSLT 3.0. In XSLT 1.0, your only recourse is to output the string with escaping disabled, then process the resulting document in second pass.

Comment: I've never understood what it's trying to achieve by "turning a string into a text node". You can do that with an xsl:value-of instruction, you don't need any kind of extension.

Comment: @MichaelKay They say it's "*helpful if you want to pass a string to a function that only accepts a node-set*". It's not very dramatic, but it should allow you to do things like `sum(amount | exsl:node-set($fee))`. -- BTW, in which implementations can you use `node-set()` to parse escaped XML?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the BTW question, but I have come across people expecting this behaviour and citing other products that (they believed) did it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Martin Honnen's comments I don't think it is possible to pass an XML node via the `<parameters>` structure of the `transform:transform()` function in eXist. The function seems to strip away any XML tags passed to it as a value.

As a workaround I will wrap both my input XML and my parameter XML into a root element and pass that as input to the transform function.

Comment: You are correct. The transform:transform function only permits strings as parameter values to the transform, the solution as you have deduced is to modify the input document to the transform to wrap your parameter node. We plan to add the now standardised fn:transform (from XQuery 3.0) to eXist in the near future to replace transform:transform, which will allow you to send nodes (or any type) as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Adam.

Answer (score 1):

To reference or transform documents from the database, you should pass the path as a parameter to the transformation, and then refer to it using a parameter and variable

```
(: xquery :)

let $path-to-document := "/db/test/testa.xml"
let $stylesheet := 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="source" required="no"/>
    <xsl:variable name="error"><error>doc not available</error></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="theDoc" select="if (doc-available($source)) then doc($source) else $error"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <result><xsl:value-of select="$source"/> - <xsl:value-of select="node-name($theDoc/*)"/></result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


return transform:transform(<dummy/>,$stylesheet, <parameters><param    name="source" value="xmldb:exist://{$path-to-document}"/></parameters>)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my XML is not in the in the database. It is an in-memory fragment.